# Define a command to affect a single sentence?

Tags: macros

Is it possible to define a command that affects everything until the end of the current sentence?

For example, I am trying to define a command using a syntax similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence.
This is the final sentence.

\end{document}
```

Where `\sentencecommand` affects only the sentence “This is the first sentence.”, but not any subsequent sentences?

Comment: as wipet shows you can use a `.` delimited argument but this fails if the sentence ends with `!` for example, and in any case breaks all latex syntax guidelines. Far better to have `\sentencecommand{This is the first sentence.}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sentence is finished by period, then you can define, for example:

```
\def\sentencecommand #1.{{\it#1}.}
```

egreg shows "right tool" from his point of view (see comments), I can show "right tool" from my point of view: OpTeX's `\eoldef` and `\replstring`. You can see that the solution is much more complicated, there is no similar `\def\foo#1.{}` but we have to define three macros.

```
\eoldef\sentencecommand#1{\def\tmp{#1}%
   \replstring\tmp{.}{\use{.}}%
   \replstring\tmp{?}{\use{?}}\replstring\tmp{!}{\use{!}}%
   \ea\sentencecommandA\tmp\use{ }%
}
\def\sentencecommandA#1\use#2{{\it#1#2}}
\def\use#1{#1}

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence.
This is the final sentence.

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence? This is the second sentence.
This is the final sentence.

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence.
This is the final sentence.

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence
and the text goes on.

\bye
```

Comment: would it be possible to check for a newline character too instead of a period ?

Comment: newline character is transformed to space at tokenizer state (i.e. before macro expansion). Without very special settings is newline character invisible from macro point of view. But scanning a parameter of a macro to the end of line is possible, for example OpTeX provides `\eoldef` for such purposes. And scannig of the separator to the end of line OR period is much more complicated.

Comment: Not really *that* complicated if you use the right tool, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for an endline, a period, an exclamation mark or a question mark. Whichever comes first ends the processing and what's found is typeset in italics.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\sentencecommand}{}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode:nn { "0D } { 12 }
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn
   { (.*?) ([\x{0d}\.]) } % anything followed by ^^M or .
   { \c{textit} { \1 } \c{__thevekat_replace:n} { \2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thevekat_replace:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { . } { .\__thevekat_remove: } { ~ \group_end: }
 }
% we need to remove a possible \endlinechar (of category 12 after the period)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thevekat_remove:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF \__thevekat_endline: { ~ \group_end: } { \group_end: }
 }
\use:x { \cs_set_eq:NN \exp_not:N \__thevekat_endline: \char_generate:nn { "0D } { 12 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence.
This is the final sentence.

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence.
This is the final sentence.

\sentencecommand This is the first sentence
and the text goes on.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not really *that* complicated: a group is opened and the `\endlinechar` is made category code 12, so we can look for it with a regular expression with `\x{0D}` (this assumes the standard value for `\endlinechar`). But the regular expression can also look for the first period, exclamation mark or question mark. What's been found is typeset in italics and the stopping character is processed: if it is the `\endlinechar` it is transformed into a space and the group is closed. Otherwise the character is typeset and an `\endlinechar` is looked for; if it is found it's transformed into a space. In either case the group is closed.

However, the syntax `\sentencecommand{This is the first sentence.}` is easier to maintain and less error prone.